# from django.contrib.auth.models import User vs defining an user ForeignKey as owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

Tags: python, django, authentication

How come to import User from the `auth` package that comes with Django, I need to do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

while to refer to the same `User` model to create a `ForeignKey`, I need to do:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
```

and not `'auth.models.User'`?

I am following the example here : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Django's *"lazy relationships"*. You can see the code for this [here](http://git.io/2eptPQ). You don't need to specify the exact module, in this case `models` because anything inheriting from Django's `models.Model` will fire off a `class_prepared` signal once it's initialised and up to this point, it's still only a string.

Just provide the app and model, or just the model name if it's in the same app.